# Angular 2+ content projection

Tags: angular

I am wondering what the best practice is for the following scenario.

I have a generic `PanelComponent` that is in charge of opening and closing itself. In it, I have `ng-content` to include whatever content.

My issue is that some content of *some* panels require the knowledge of when the panel is visible and when it's hidden. The issue is, of course, is that the state of hidden/visible is encapsulated in the `PanelComponent`.

What is a good way or best practice in this case for communicating the state to the component that is injected as part of the content projection into `ng-content` of `PanelComponent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to acces `PanelComponent` properties via template variables:

```
<panel #p1>
  <p [class.parent-visible]="p1.visible">some content</p>
</panel>
<panel #p2>
  <p [class.parent-visible]="p2.visible">other content</p>
</panel>
```

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right... What bothered me about this approach is that I am forced to expose state of `panel`... Wanted to make it opening/closing a self-contained type of functionality, but not sure what I was thinking... If that inner component needs this (which is probably bad design, which I inherited), then there isn't much I can do, but expose `panel`'s state. Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring to component interaction. 
One way to achieve it is by using input and output parameters.
I suggest you to look at this part of angular documentation

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction